# Automatically start forever (node) on system restart

Tags: node.js, centos, forever

I am using node's forever module to keep my node server running. Forever however terminates when there is a system restart. Is there any way I can automatically start the node server (with forever) when the system restarts?

Comment: Is this server in the cloud? Do you have any boot scripts for it?

Comment: Checkout [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)! It also supports startup script generation (systemd, systemv...) http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Answer (score 349):

I would suggest using crontab.  It's easy to use.

### How to

1. To start editing run the following replacing the "testuser" with your desired runtime user for the node process.  If you choose a different user other than yourself, you will have to run this with sudo.

   ```
   $ crontab -u testuser -e
   ```
2. If you have never done this before, it will ask you which editor you wish to edit with.  I like vim, but will recommend nano for ease of use.
3. Once in the editor add the following line:

   ```
   @reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start /your/path/to/your/app.js
   ```
4. Save the file.  You should get some feedback that the cron has been installed.
5. For further confirmation of the installation of the cron, execute the following (again replacing "testuser" with your target username) to list the currently installed crons:

   ```
   $ crontab -u testuser -l
   ```

Note that in my opinion, you should always use full paths when executing binaries in cron.
Also, if the path to your forever script is not correct, run `which forever` to get the full path.

Given that `forever` calls `node`, you may also want to provide the full path to `node`:

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start -c /usr/local/bin/node /your/path/to/your/app.js
```

### Further Reading

- [crontab Man Page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab)
- [Ubuntu Cron HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Comment: Any tips on what to check if this seems not to do anything?

Comment: This approach is good, but only for those cases when the system gets rebooted. If the server is shutted down and then powered on - this cron job won't execute.

Comment: What makes you think that?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Predefined_scheduling_definitions Explains that `@reboot` cron's get run on the cron deamon starting.  To add I have never come across a situation that would suggest that my cron's that are set at `@reboot` don't run on system boot.  The way you shut it down is irrelevant for this.

Comment: @JulianLannigan I love the idea of using crontab over an init script for the simplicity of the solution. Are there any disadvantages (other than having the ability to perhaps restart on the command line) to using your solution over a more traditional init script approach?

Comment: With an init script could you do service myapp stop? It would be handy for pausing the server, and I'm not sure what the best way to do that is.

Comment: @Stephen this is not an init script, rather it uses the forever library to manage the daemon. All the cron reboot directive does is start your daemon. After that you can do whatever you want via the forever library. See https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever#using-forever-from-the-command-line

Comment: Adding `@reboot` entries to my crontab didn't work for me; neither did the same entries (minus `@reboot`, of course) in `/etc/rc.local`. **That is**, until I prefaced the entries with `/usr/bin/sudo -u {user}`. Therefore, **I think Step 1 ought to be amended.** I tested this form both with and without invoking `/usr/bin/sudo`; it only works with: `(cd /path/to/; /usr/bin/sudo -u myuser /usr/local/bin/forever start /path/to/app.js)`.

Comment: @JulianLannigan I was referencing what Tom said. I think I would rather have an init script since I need an easy way to start/stop/restart via command line in 1 command.

Comment: @Arthur You shouldn't have to run sudo from within the crontab. That is why if you want to run it as a different user than yourself, you specify that in the `-u`.  Using that writes/edits the crontab for that specific user and when the daemon is started it will process all user's crontabs as their respective users.

Comment: @Stephen That's the point of `forever`! Read the docs for you can do all that with "one command". 

`forever start /your/path/to/your/app.js`
`forever stop /your/path/to/your/app.js`
`forever restart /your/path/to/your/app.js`

https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever#using-forever-from-the-command-line

Comment: I get that, but it would be cool to do "forever stop app-alias" rather than that behemoth of a command. I guess it just comes down to preference. I like to find the most elegant solution I can.

Comment: it appears `/home` is not mounted yet, so this won't work if your code lives in `/home`.

Comment: This approach does not work for me. When my server reboots, forever does not start. Even if I logged in with the user account remotely via SSH, forever still does not run. I am using CentOS x86 6.5.

Comment: I found that the above failed for me because node is not in the path when cron tries to run forever, even with the -c option. However, it turns out that you can add a PATH= statement directly in the crontab as long as it is above the schedule statements. Once PATH is set the the @reboot statement worked like a dream.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @chovy, it was very helpful. For those using environment variables from bashrc, mind his comment. Since /home is not mounted it won't work. Set the variables at the crontab command like `@reboot varname=value ...`

Comment: for me it started on reboot, I can see servers using command forever list, but they do not work. WHen I manually start save node server - it works, even when it is already started on reboot.

Comment: It worked for me but I am a little bit concerned on simple shutdowns and restart. It will work?

Comment: @chovy `home` is definitely mounted but I can't say the same if using `~`

Comment: if '/home' doesn't work: where else should an app be installed? So it can be used with the user's credentials? (sorry I'm a ubuntu noob)

Comment: App created by express.js use `bin/www` to start service, and `bin/www` use `#!/usr/bin/env node` syntax to require node.js to process it, unfortunately `/usr/local/bin` not in the boot PATH, so my solution is putting the following line at the top of my crontab file: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` to expand the root users PATH variable, that works for me

Answer (score 128):

You can use forever-service for doing this.

```
npm install -g forever-service
forever-service install test
```

This will provision app.js in the current directory as a service via forever. The service will automatically restart every time system is restarted. Also when stopped it will attempt a graceful stop. This script provisions the logrotate script as well.

Github url: [https://github.com/zapty/forever-service](http://github.com/zapty/forever-service)

NOTE: I am the author of forever-service.

Comment: That is great! How can I pass NODE_ENV with forever-service?

Comment: Use  -e "PORT=80 ENV=prod FOO=bar" option

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why, but I couldn't get cron to work and this did the trick.

Comment: I don't get how to run forever-service. What is that "test" in "forever-service install test"? My command to start my app forever is: "/usr/local/bin/forever start -c /usr/local/bin/node /home/alex/public/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server -s -d false". What would I have to write?

Comment: test here is the name of the service. when you run forever-service install test it creates a service called test, to run app.js in that directory to be run as a service. I would suggest reading the help documentation on the gihub page, and add a issue there if you are unable to understand it.

Comment: Brilliant little tool.  Thank you.  Took like 2 seconds to set up, works like a champ.
This answer deserves more up-votes for this specific use case.

Comment: @Alex - to clarify arva's comment - in the example `forever-service install test`, `test` will be the name of the **service**, but not the name of the actual program / node .js file to run.  By default, it assumes the name of the program is `app.js`, but you can override it with the `--script` flag, as follows: `forever-service install test --script main.js`.  (Untested, so please correct me if there's any syntax detail wrong.)

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Thanks for answering. I am now using PM2 which works beautifully. Instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: @Alex That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Best app ever!!! Creates service in few keystrokes, all stdout is written to separate log file in /var/log directory for each service you created(still don't know if stderr is written separately). 100% recommended!

Comment: Windows OS users, beware that it is not supported yet, I just realized when I fire install service command!

Comment: Doesn't work on latest Ubuntu because of missing Upstart

Comment: windows os is not supported

Comment: forever-service is the best feature forever package must have... but never had.

Answer (score 34):

1. Install PM2 globally using NPM

   `npm install pm2 -g`
2. Start your script with pm2

   `pm2 start app.js`
3. generate an active startup script

   `pm2 startup`

   NOTE: pm2 startup is for startting the PM2 when the system reboots. PM2 once started, restarts all the processes it had been managing before the system went down.

In case you want to disable the automatic startup, simply use pm2 unstartup

If you want the startup script to be executed under another user, just use the `-u <username>` option and the `--hp <user_home>:`

Comment: Please don't post the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44337452/4687348) to multiple questions.

Comment: I really love how pm2 is refined, and comes with an awesome monitoring tool. Hope this is highlighted more for others.

@rv7 I'm sure you saw this, but there is a windows solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-service. Haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: This looks way easier than jiggling with forever and forever-service.

Answer (score 28):

This case is valid for Debian.

Add the following to `/etc/rc.local`

`/usr/bin/sudo -u {{user}} /usr/local/bin/forever start {{app path}}`

- `{{user}}` replaces your username.
- `{{app path}}` replaces your app path. For example, `/var/www/test/app.js`

Comment: This method doesn't deal with graceful shutdowns, though for lots of people this is probably not an issue.

Comment: BTW - I think you should be editing `/etc/rc.local`, not `/etc/init.d/rc.local`

Comment: Agree with @UpTheCreek that /etc/rc.local is the more appropriate place to add this - see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59945 for a great explanation.

Comment: Also, you may want to specify the 'current working directory' in `app.js` to ensure relative files are loaded correctly -   `process.chdir('/your/path/to/your/app');`   Node.js ref docs [here](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory)

Comment: If you need to set environment variables for your Node.JS script (like $PORT for express), adding the following line to `/etc/rc.local` did the trick for me: `( cd /path/to/project && /usr/bin/sudo -u {{user}} env PORT={{port number}} PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin sh -c "forever start app.js" )`

Comment: Using sudo to change the user outputs this error in the error log of rc.local: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

Answer (score 13):

An alternative crontab method inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13388741/1928926) answer and [this](http://www.hacksparrow.com/make-forever-reboot-proof-with-cron.html) blog post.

**1. Create a bash script file (change bob to desired user).**

```
vi /home/bob/node_server_init.sh
```

**2. Copy and paste this inside the file you've just created.**

```
#!/bin/sh

export NODE_ENV=production
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
forever start /node/server/path/server.js > /dev/null
```

Make sure to edit the paths above according to your config!

**3. Make sure the bash script can be executed.**

```
chmod 700 /home/bob/node_server_init.sh
```

**4. Test the bash script.**

```
sh /home/bob/node_server_init.sh
```

**5. Replace "bob" with the runtime user for node.**

```
crontab -u bob -e
```

**6. Copy and paste (change bob to desired user).**

```
@reboot /bin/sh /home/bob/node_server_init.sh
```

Save the crontab.

**You've made it to the end, your prize is a reboot (to test) :)**

Comment: This method worked best for me. Forever would quit out when I put a full path to the server.js file. If I ran it in the same directory, foreveer would work fine. The reason it failed is the server.js file included other files, but the paths were messed up. Using this method, I could CD in my .sh script to the directory, then run everything relative to there.

Answer (score 9):

Copied answer from the attached [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701259/how-to-make-a-node-js-application-run-permanently/40254977#40254977).

You can use [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), it's a production process manager for Node.js applications with a built-in load balancer.

Install PM2

```
$ npm install pm2 -g
```

Start an application

```
$ pm2 start app.js
```

If you using express then you can start your app like

```
pm2 start ./bin/www --name="app"
```

Listing all running processes:

```
$ pm2 list
```

It will list all process. You can then stop / restart your service by using ID or Name of the app with following command.

```
$ pm2 stop all                  
$ pm2 stop 0                    
$ pm2 restart all
```

To display logs

```
$ pm2 logs ['all'|app_name|app_id]
```

Comment: How does it start **AUTOMATICALLY** on system boot? You just copy/pasted CLI manual typing

Comment: @Green ,
Run,
```$pm2 startup```
After that you will see pm2 asking to manually run a command,  copy and run that.
Then,
```$pm2 save```
Now your app.js will survive system reboots

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a shell script in the /etc/init.d folder for that. It's sort of complicated if you never have done it but there is plenty of information on the web on init.d scripts.

Here is a sample a script that I created to run a CoffeeScript site with forever:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# initd-example      Node init.d 
#
# chkconfig: 345 
# description: Script to start a coffee script application through forever
# processname: forever/coffeescript/node
# pidfile: /var/run/forever-initd-hectorcorrea.pid 
# logfile: /var/run/forever-initd-hectorcorrea.log
#
# Based on a script posted by https://gist.github.com/jinze at https://gist.github.com/3748766
#


# Source function library.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions


pidFile=/var/run/forever-initd-hectorcorrea.pid 
logFile=/var/run/forever-initd-hectorcorrea.log 

sourceDir=/home/hectorlinux/website
coffeeFile=app.coffee
scriptId=$sourceDir/$coffeeFile


start() {
    echo "Starting $scriptId"

    # This is found in the library referenced at the top of the script
    start_daemon

    # Start our CoffeeScript app through forever
    # Notice that we change the PATH because on reboot
    # the PATH does not include the path to node.
    # Launching forever or coffee with a full path
    # does not work unless we set the PATH.
    cd $sourceDir
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
    NODE_ENV=production PORT=80 forever start --pidFile $pidFile -l $logFile -a -d --sourceDir $sourceDir/ -c coffee $coffeeFile

    RETVAL=$?
}

restart() {
    echo -n "Restarting $scriptId"
    /usr/local/bin/forever restart $scriptId
    RETVAL=$?
}

stop() {
    echo -n "Shutting down $scriptId"
    /usr/local/bin/forever stop $scriptId
    RETVAL=$?
}

status() {
    echo -n "Status $scriptId"
    /usr/local/bin/forever list
    RETVAL=$?
}


case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    status)
        status
        ;;
    restart)
        restart
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage:  {start|stop|status|restart}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

I had to make sure the folder and PATHs were explicitly set or available to the root user since init.d scripts are ran as root.

Comment: If you have any dependencies that are also started with init.d you might have loading order issues though.

Comment: @alexandru.topliceanu I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

Which is the best option to run the server production server

What are the advantages of running your application this way?

- PM2 will automatically restart your application if it crashes.
- PM2 will keep a log of your unhandled exceptions - in this case, in a file at /home/safeuser/.pm2/logs/app-err.log.
- With one command, PM2 can ensure that any applications it manages restart when the server reboots. Basically, your node application will start as a service.

ref: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Answer (score 5):

Forever was not made to get node applications running as services. The right approach is to either create an /etc/inittab entry (old linux systems) or an upstart (newer linux systems).

Here's some documentation on how to set this up as an upstart:
https://github.com/cvee/node-upstart

Comment: Upstart failed me on CentOS and I read that it's going to disappear. Creating an init.d entry isn't really the most user friendly way, but it's linux I suppose :)

Answer (score 5):

`crontab` does not work for me on CentOS x86 6.5. @reboot seems to be not working.

Finally I got this solution:

**Edit:** `/etc/rc.local`

```
sudo vi /etc/rc.local
```

Add this line to the end of the file. Change `USER_NAME` and `PATH_TO_PROJECT` to your own. `NODE_ENV=production` means the app runs in production mode. You can add more lines if you need to run more than one node.js app.

```
su - USER_NAME -c "NODE_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/forever start /PATH_TO_PROJECT/app.js"
```

Don't set `NODE_ENV` in a separate line, your app will still run in development mode, because forever does not get `NODE_ENV`.

```
# WRONG!
su - USER_NAME -c "export NODE_ENV=production"
```

Save and quit vi (press `ESC : w q return`). You can try rebooting your server. After your server reboots, your node.js app should run automatically, even if you don't log into any account remotely via ssh.

You'd better set `NODE_ENV` environment in your shell. `NODE_ENV` will be set automatically when your account `USER_NAME` logs in.

```
echo export NODE_ENV=production >> ~/.bash_profile
```

So you can run commands like forever stop/start `/PATH_TO_PROJECT/app.js` via ssh without setting `NODE_ENV` again.

Comment: got same problem on debian 7.6. This fixed for me. Many thanks.

Comment: Just in case that you don't want to use 'forever', you can change the line to 'su - USER_NAME -c "NODE_ENV=production node /PATH_TO_PROJECT/bin/www"'.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a script that does exactly this:

https://github.com/chovy/node-startup

I have not tried with forever, but you can customize the command it runs, so it should be straight forward:

```
/etc/init.d/node-app start
/etc/init.d/node-app restart
/etc/init.d/node-app stop
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with rc.local is that the commands are accessed as root which is different than logging to as a user and using sudo.

I solved this problem by adding a .sh script with the startup commands i want to etc/profile.d. Any .sh file in profile.d will load automatically and any command will be treated as if you used the regular sudo.

The only downside to this is the specified user needs to loggin for things to start which in my situation was always the case.

Answer (score 1):

I tried lots of the above answers. None of them worked for me. My app is installed in `/home` and as user, not as root. This probably means that when the above mentioned start scripts run, `/home` is not mounted yet, so the app is not started.

Then I found these instructions by Digital Ocean:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Using PM2 as explained was very simple and works perfectly: My virtual servers had two physical crashes since - downtime was only about a minute.

Comment: PM2 has much more stars (2x) on github, than forever, and it has more features as well. I think most of the answers are obsolete here.

Answer (score 0):

complete example crontab (located at /etc/crontab) ..

```
#!/bin/bash

# edit this file with .. crontab -u root -e
# view this file with .. crontab -u root -l

# put your path here if it differs
PATH=/root/bin:/root/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

# * * * * * echo "executes once every minute" > /root/deleteme

@reboot cd /root/bible-api-dbt-server; npm run forever;
@reboot cd /root/database-api-server; npm run forever;
@reboot cd /root/mailer-api-server; npm run forever;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found my own solution by using serve & npm as follows:

- Install serve package: `npm install -g serve`
- Then have the command `serve -s /var/www/sitename` to execute on reboot.

This is what works for me on my VPS.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following command in your shell to start your node forever:

```
forever app.js //my node script
```

You need to keep in mind that the server on which your app is running should always be kept on.