# Run nodejs app on start Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, web-services, windows-server-2012

I have a nodejs app which should start running when windows starts. As I'm new to node and have never done anything similar I don't know how to do it. I have been reading some articles from several webs that use [AdvancedInstaller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiD3ECIqPdI) or other software but don't know if there are any ways to do it without using other software. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

There are other packages aimed at making pm2 a windows service:

[pm2-windows-startup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-startup)

[pm2-windows-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-service)

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you need to create `*.sh` script and put in the  Startup folder
maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385029/automatically-start-forever-node-on-system-restart) can help you 
or just google `sh script startup nodejs windows`