# How to execute my command every 4 hours in crontab in ubuntu(forever module nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, linux, cron, forever

I am executing the below command first,

```
crontab -u user_name -e

# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for this particular task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

The above file gets displayed.
And i have added my command to the next line in the above file

```
0 */4 * * * forever restart /var/www/html/app.js
```

But the above command is not executing.
The file path for my app.js file is '/var/www/html/'.
What i actually need is my web services in nodejs  are going down frequently after 8 hours after it getting started(This is not the db issue as my db is not going idle) so i am prefering to restart it every 4 hours after it gets started using crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385029/automatically-start-forever-node-on-system-restart) have you tried to use `/usr/local/bin/forever` instead of 'forever'?

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the PATH is set or not by typing echo $PATH in the terminal,if the PATH is not set means then set the PATH as 
the result of

```
echo $PATH
```

PATH=(result of above command)
After that you can use this command to run the cron by

```
5 * * * * cd /path/to/your/project/ folder && /usr/local/bin/forever startall > /tmp/file.txt

> /tmp/file.txt
```

is to check whether the cron has working or not.if worked you will have the file.txt as log in your temp folder.