# run node with forever and npm script

Tags: node.js, npm, environment, forever

System: ubuntu 16

I have a working node app on a server. In package.json there is script with options to execute:

```
 - "start-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./bin/www" 
 - "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www"
 - "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./bin/www"
```

What is needed:

- use a service that would start app on server reboot and generally
  keep it running all the time (I am using forever now).
- Start an app as npm script from package.json source from root directory

Right now I can start forever by going to app directory and typing this command:

```
forever start ./bin/www
```

but there is no control over the environment.

Additionally, when I try this from root directory - it fails:

```
forever start /home/myapp/bin/www
```

How can I start forever from root directory AND using npm script? 
I assume that initial script should be placed in

> /etc/rc.local

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically start forever (node) on system restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385029/automatically-start-forever-node-on-system-restart)

Comment: Your use case is only for local development or you want a solution for deploy you app on server?

Comment: for production use as well

Answer (score 1):

For deploying on server, You should give [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) a try.

> Advanced, production process manager for Node.js

Comment: Thanks for advice. Could you give me a hint on why my present config fails?