# How to run again Node.js file (example.js) after server (VPS) reboot?

Tags: node.js, cron, cpanel, reboot

I run my node.js file on a vps. My file called server.js
For some reasons company reboot the system. 
So my server.js file stop working.
Any way how automatically run server.js file?

I try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever but not results

### Command

```
forever start server.js
```

This command work for the moment but when my system (vps) reboot node.js file stop working!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically start forever (node) on system restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385029/automatically-start-forever-node-on-system-restart)

Comment: I think this is solution but i can set it up to my vps server