# How to auto-run my scala app in the Play framework on Linux upon server reboot?

Tags: linux, scala, playframework

all. I'm not even a newbie -- I'm a sub-newbie.  We have a tool running in Linux written in Scala using the Play framework. I'm light on my Linux experience and have zero experience with Play or Scala.

The app crashed the other day and when we rebooted the server we hoped it would auto-restart the app. Alas, it did not. I finally figured out where the app was, what it was written in, and how to get it running.

The problem is it is only running in my terminal window and, of course, when I logout the app will stop running.

**Question**: how do I get it to auto-run when the server is rebooted? The command I use when running it in my terminal window is from the root directory of the app with this command:  `play run`

It's Amazon Linux (https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2015.03-release-notes), play! 2.1.1 (using Java 1.7.0_79 and Scala 2.10.0).

Thank you.

Comment: [Related resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) and [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275870/how-can-i-automatically-start-a-node-js-application-in-amazon-linux-ami-on-aws)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is [sbt-native-packager](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production#The-Native-Packager). It will create `unix` package from your `Play` app. Upon installation, your app will be installed as service - it will start on boot.