# Node JS running on Synology Nas, accessing ssh Windows Powershell, port forward, Linux upstart (.conf) script running the app.js permanently

Tags: node.js, ssh, portforwarding, upstart, synology

The Nas I used at home has installed Node JS v12 from Synology's package center. So I thought it would be cool to create a Node JS http webserver and study myself into back-end and front end development.

Create volume1/path_to_your_app/app.js and let the http server listen to port 8080.
Next, With Powershell I could login with my Synology (admin) account's [username] and [password] into the Nas through ip-address from home. For accessing with ssh in Synology's cofiguration/Terminal the ssh-service must be checked. The default portnumber is 22, I changed this to for example 8822. Next, from Powershell I could now run the command:

- ssh username@192.168.1.44 -p8822
- Next password will be prompted

From Synology's shell I could now navigate to the file, run it and view it in my browser at 192.168.1.44:8080/.

- cd /volume1/path_to_your_app/
- node app.js

Next I setup port forwarding to host the webserver online. In my routers settings/port forwarding ipv4/ my nas is defined under an ip-address 192.168.1.44. At the Nas's application configuration I added a new rule under TCP protocol on port 8080. It only works for port 8080 (as far as I could get it workingfor now) because this is an experimental port. I could now access my webserver on my router's WAN-IP:8080/.
After I exit the Synology's shell (ctrl+c) my application also stops running. I was not able to install forever from npm to keep the server running. However from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275870/how-can-i-automatically-start-a-node-js-application-in-amazon-linux-ami-on-aws) I found a solution. I had to create an upstart file from Synology's shell in the /etc/init folder.

- cd /      (go back to root)
- cd /etc/init/
- sudo vi yourappname.conf
- the I copy/pasted this code in the (.conf) file AND editted the parameters to my enviroment:

```
#!upstart
description "your app name"
start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
respawn limit 99 5

env NODE_ENV=development
# Warning: this runs node as root user, which is a security risk
# in many scenarios, but upstart-ing a process as a non-root user
# is outside the scope of this question

chdir /volume1/path_to_your_app/
exec node /volume1/path_to_your_app/app.js >> /var/log/yourappname.log 2>&1
```

Now I could start and stop the upstart script manually from Synology's shell and it keeps on running even after I exit the Synology's shell. I also inserted "chdir /path_to_your_app/" in the script before "exec" because it changes the directory from where Node JS is running to the directory from your app. I don't know what security risks are from the warning in the script.

- sudo start yourappname
- sudo stop yourappname

Debugging my Node JS application i do with the commands:

- sudo tail -f /var/log/yourappname.log

Comment: It would be a good answer to the question "How can I run a persistent node.js application on a synology nas?"

Comment: Hey thanks for your interest! You are right i did not ask a question. With this post i meant to document how i managed for my first time to execute code with a Node JS enviroment and all of it's native libraries. However i did not mention soon after i realised that Synology blocks me from installing any external libraries from NPM in Node JS from Synology's package center. So i installed Docker from Synology's package center and managed to create two images from Node JS and MongoDB. On the Docker image from Node JS i was finally able to install MongoDB from NPM (which is an external library).

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. How can I modify this config so that service also starts on machine restart?

Comment: Save an upstart script in a .conf file in /etc/init (if you need it to run as root when the system boots up) https://askubuntu.com/a/910

To tell you ther truth, i did not get this to work on my Synology. However i've been using Docker and Docker has restart policies:
1. https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/
2. docker run --restart: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/
3. docker-compose.yml: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart

Comment: Does the synology NAS does not have a "Application" or "Startup" setting? I dide the same with node on my synology nas and the application started automaticly. I dont rembember exectly where, but i know that is was configruable through the GUI. Startup task or Applications... There you should be able to start your app automaticly on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you wrote the Warning because it can be solved by one command
`setuid <username>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).